# Issue with session in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am writing a rails app that involves a cart system stored in `session`. I did some googling and it turned out I can store the ID of my cart in the session hash like this `session[:cart_id]`. However, I noticed that if I open a new tab in my rails app, it still uses the same session. This means that multiple tabs of the app share the same cart. I don't want this to happen. Ideally, each browser should get its own cart. Is there any way I can resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the same browser, you'll always have the same session.

In Rails, the concept of session is implemented through cookies. And cookies are stored client-side on the browser, specific to each website.

(I could be entirely wrong, but I'd like to think the answer is no.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there anyway to use session storage in rails? Can that resolve the issue?